# Convert text pasted from Word into a Firefox rich-text editor to xsl-fo while preserving formatting (Java) (Apache FOP)

Tags: java, xml, xslt, ms-word, xsl-fo

I have a Java-based content management system into which company employees enter reports into a web form, with the body of the report being output into a rich text field. These reports can then be output to PDF using XSL-FO.

A common practice by employees (that I am in no position to change or argue with) is to prepare reports in Microsoft Word, then copy-paste those reports into the CMS.

The browser rich-text box does an acceptable job retaining and displaying the MS Word content's formatting. However, when converting to PDF in FO, most of the formatting is lost. One of the most common complaints is that table column and row sizes are broken.

To illustrate, something that looks like this in word:

[word doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTexA.png)

Will look like this in the browser:

[browser rtf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzNun.png)

But then look like this in the pdf:

[pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iF9v.png)

Broadly, my question here is how can I go about converting the pasted MS Office content into FO while preserving the original formatting? Is there a library that does this?

---

Some things which may or may not be helpful and may or may not be obvious to whomever might happen to help out with this question.

The pasted Word content gets stored in our database as follows:

`<p>Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words.</p>  <p>Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words.</p>  <p>Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words.</p>  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">  <tbody><tr>   <td width="208" valign="top">   <p>test</p>   </td>   <td width="44" valign="top">   <p>b</p>   </td>   <td width="372" valign="top">   <p>cd</p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr>   <td width="208" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="44" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="372" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr>   <td width="208" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="44" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="372" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr>   <td width="208" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="44" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="372" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr>   <td width="208" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="44" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="372" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr>   <td width="208" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="44" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="372" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr>   <td width="208" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="44" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>   <td width="372" valign="top">   <p>&nbsp;</p>   </td>  </tr> </tbody></table>  <p>&nbsp;</p>  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>        </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>     Normal   0               false   false   false      EN-US   X-NONE   X-NONE                                                                                             </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 10]> <style>  /* Style Definitions */  table.MsoNormalTable  {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";     mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;  mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;  mso-style-noshow:yes;   mso-style-priority:99;  mso-style-parent:"";    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;    mso-para-margin-top:0in;    mso-para-margin-right:0in;  mso-para-margin-bottom:8.0pt;   mso-para-margin-left:0in;   line-height:107%;   mso-pagination:widow-orphan;    font-size:11.0pt;   font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;   mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;  mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;   mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;  mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;   mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";     mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;} table.MsoTableGrid     {mso-style-name:"Table Grid";   mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;  mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;  mso-style-priority:39;  mso-style-unhide:no;    border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;   mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;    mso-border-insideh:.5pt solid windowtext;   mso-border-insidev:.5pt solid windowtext;   mso-para-margin:0in;    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;    font-size:11.0pt;   font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;   mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;  mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;   mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;  mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;   mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";     mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;} </style> <![endif]-->`

So, it seems like it's a matter of extracting the MS stylesheet from the content and then translating that into something that FOP (Apache FO Processor, which is what we use to convert to / display FO) understands?

It looks like the table sizing is stored in the table tags itself, but it looks like the problem there is a series of the following errors when converting:

> 10/11/19 11:03 AM: Error in width property value '208':
>   org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyException: No conversion defined
>   10/11/19 11:03 AM: Error in width property value '44':
>   org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyException: No conversion defined
>   10/11/19 11:03 AM: Error in width property value '372':
>   org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyException: No conversion defined

How would I go about defining a conversion from MS's width numbers to something FOP understands?

Note: This is an older CMS running on Java 1.5, using Apache Fop .20.5. If there is a library that does what I'm asking for and it's not compatible, I'm hoping it's open source so I can conceivably "downgrade" it to work with Java 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

The `width` property should be a length or a percentage (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#width).  To get past your immediate problem, your XSLT should add a unit after the number when generating the XSL-FO that you feed to FOP.

Something like `width="208px"` or even `width="208pt"` should stop FOP from complaining.  When you get to the point of being able to generate PDF, you might find that 208px is too wide or too narrow, so you might need to scale the number as part of the processing (or you might be able to modify FOP's idea of the number of pixels per inch).